# Navigating by Pressing Images

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

[image: screenshot]

I am trying to navigate screens by pressing on specific images on `SearchScreen.js`. Each image leads to a different screen. I am currently trying to navigate from the first image to the screen `meo_sw.js`. However, I am not being able to do so and I don't undersand why. Here is the code of `SearchScreen.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { ScrollView, StyleSheet, TextInput, Text, View, Image, TouchableOpacity, TouchableWithoutFeedback} from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';

function SearchScreen() {

 return (
<View style={styles.screen}>
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <TextInput style={styles.inputBox}
              underlineColorAndroid='rgba(0,0,0,0)' 
              placeholder="Procura aqui"
              placeholderTextColor = "black"
              selectionColor="black"
              keyboardType="default"/>
  </View>
  <View style={styles.teste}> 
    <Text style={styles.festivais}>Recomendados</Text>
    <ScrollView horizontal={true} showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false} style={styles.festivais_lista}>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigate('meo_sw')}>
        <Image source={require('../assets/images/meo_sudoeste.png')} style={styles.image}/>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('vodaf_coura')}>
        <Image source={require('../assets/images/vodafone_coura.png')} style={styles.image} />
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('superR_superB')}>
        <Image source={require('../assets/images/superbock_superrock.png')} style={styles.image}/>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('nos_primavera')}>
        <Image source={require('../assets/images/nos_primavera.png')} style={styles.image}/>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('rock_in_rio')}>
        <Image source={require('../assets/images/rock_in_rio.png')} style={styles.image}/>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('edp_cool_jazz')}>
        <Image source={require('../assets/images/edp_cooljazz.png')} style={styles.image}/>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </ScrollView>
  </View>
</View>
);
}

SearchScreen.navigationOptions = {
  title: 'Procurar',
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
 //I took this off because it's irrelevant for the question itself
});

export default SearchScreen;
```

And here is the screen 'meo_sw.js':

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, Text, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';

const meo_sw = props => {

return(
<View style={styles.header}>
    <Text style={styles.texto}>Meo Sudoeste</Text>
</View>
)
};

const styles=StyleSheet.create({
//Irrelevant
})

export default meo_sw;
```

The error says simply:

> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: navigate

Please help me

*UPDATED*

This is the `MainTabNavigator.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Platform } from 'react-native';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation-tabs';

import TabBarIcon from '../components/TabBarIcon';
import HomeScreen from '../screens/HomeScreen';
import SearchScreen from '../screens/SearchScreen';
import SettingsScreen from '../screens/SettingsScreen';
import ChatScreen from '../screens/ChatScreen';
import CalendarScreen from '../screens/CalendarScreen';
import meo_sw from '../Eventos/Festivais/meo_sw';

const config = Platform.select({
  web: { headerMode: 'screen' },
  default: {},
});

//Home

const HomeStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
HomeScreen: {screen: HomeScreen},
SearchScreen: {screen: SearchScreen},
ChatScreen: {screen: ChatScreen},
SettingsScreen: {screen: SettingsScreen},
CalendarScreen: {screen: CalendarScreen},
  },
  config
);

HomeStack.navigationOptions = {
  tabBarLabel: 'Home',
  tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
    <TabBarIcon
      focused={focused}
      name={
        Platform.OS === 'ios'
          ? `ios-home${focused ? '' : '-outline'}`
          : 'md-home'
      }
    />
  ),
};

HomeStack.path = '';

//Search

const SearchStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Search: SearchScreen,
  },
  config
);

SearchStack.navigationOptions = {
  tabBarLabel: 'Procurar',
  tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
    <TabBarIcon focused={focused} name={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'ios-search' : 'md-search'} />
  ),
};

SearchStack.path = '';

//Chat

const ChatStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Chat: ChatScreen,
  },
  config
);

ChatStack.navigationOptions = {
  tabBarLabel: 'Chat',
  tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
    <TabBarIcon
      focused={focused}
      name={
        Platform.OS === 'ios'
          ? `ios-chatboxes${focused ? '' : '-outline'}`
          : 'md-chatboxes'
      }
    />
  ),
};

ChatStack.path = '';


//Settings

const SettingsStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Settings: SettingsScreen,
  },
  config
);

SettingsStack.navigationOptions = {
  tabBarLabel: 'Perfil',
  tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
    <TabBarIcon focused={focused} name={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'ios-person' : 'md-person'} />
  ),
};

SettingsStack.path = '';

//Calendar

const CalendarStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Calendar: CalendarScreen,
  },
  config
);

 CalendarStack.navigationOptions = {
  tabBarLabel: 'Calendário',
  tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
    <TabBarIcon focused={focused} name={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'ios-calendar' : 'md-calendar'} />
  ),
};

CalendarStack.path = '';

//Bottom tab navigator

const tabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
  SearchStack,
  CalendarStack,
  HomeStack,
  ChatStack,
  SettingsStack
});

tabNavigator.path = '';


export default tabNavigator;
```

And this is the `AppNavigator.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { createAppContainer, createSwitchNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import MainTabNavigator from './MainTabNavigator';

export default createAppContainer(
  createSwitchNavigator({
    Main: MainTabNavigator,
  })
);
```

Comment: can you update the screenshot of error ?

Comment: I updated the the question with a screenshot

Comment: try **this.props.navigation.push('vodaf_coura')}**

Comment: I replaced it but now the error is "TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.props')

Comment: pass props in function **function SearchScreen({ navigation }) **

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass navigation object as prop.

```
function SearchScreen({ navigation }) {
 ....
}
```

The use it like

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('meo_sw')}>
  <Image source={require('../assets/images/meo_sudoeste.png')} style={styles.image}/>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Add the screen to one of your navigators, like the following.

```
const HomeStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    HomeScreen: { screen: HomeScreen },
    SearchScreen: { screen: SearchScreen },
    ChatScreen: { screen: ChatScreen },
    SettingsScreen: { screen: SettingsScreen },
    CalendarScreen: { screen: CalendarScreen },
    meo_sw: { screen: meo_sw}
  },
  config
);

HomeStack.navigationOptions = {
  tabBarLabel: 'Home',
  tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
    <TabBarIcon
      focused={focused}
      name={
        Platform.OS === 'ios'
          ? `ios-home${focused ? '' : '-outline'}`
          : 'md-home'
      }
    />
  ),
};
```

[Expo example](https://snack.expo.io/@lekgwaraj/rn5)

Comment: I tried this but now when I click on the image it no longer returns a an error and instead nothing happens

Comment: do you have screen named ```meo_sw```? please share your navigation code.

Comment: it's doing nothing because the screen doesn't exists,

Comment: The screen does exist, it is called 'meo_sw.js'. The code is written in the question

Comment: I updated the question. The AppNavigator.js is then imported to the App.js

Comment: you are not using ```meo_sw``` in navigation as a screen, you need to add it the navigation.

Comment: Do I add it on MainTabNavigator.js ? But I don't want to have the bottom tab icon to this screen

Comment: I want it to be an independent screen from the bottom tab

Comment: Do I import meo_sw to MainTabNavigator.js and then do SearchStack.path = 'meo_sw'; ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208325/discussion-between-junius-l-and-tiago-2-0).

Answer (score -1):

your Function is unable to get the props so that its not importing navigation property !!
change the function into class and get the props in class and then try navigating.
**try this code**

```
export default class SearchScreen extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {    }
              }

  return (
<View style={styles.screen}>
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <TextInput style={styles.inputBox}
              underlineColorAndroid='rgba(0,0,0,0)' 
              placeholder="Procura aqui"
              placeholderTextColor = "black"
              selectionColor="black"
              keyboardType="default"/>
  </View>
  <View style={styles.teste}> 
    <Text style={styles.festivais}>Recomendados</Text>
    <ScrollView horizontal={true} showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false} style={styles.festivais_lista}>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('meo_sw')}>
        <Image source={require('../assets/images/meo_sudoeste.png')} style={styles.image}/>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('vodaf_coura')}>
        <Image source={require('../assets/images/vodafone_coura.png')} style={styles.image} />
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('superR_superB')}>
        <Image source={require('../assets/images/superbock_superrock.png')} style={styles.image}/>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('nos_primavera')}>
        <Image source={require('../assets/images/nos_primavera.png')} style={styles.image}/>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('rock_in_rio')}>
        <Image source={require('../assets/images/rock_in_rio.png')} style={styles.image}/>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('edp_cool_jazz')}>
        <Image source={require('../assets/images/edp_cooljazz.png')} style={styles.image}/>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </ScrollView>
  </View>
</View>
);
}
```

Hope it helps , feel free for doubts.

Comment: Because we can create lot of functions in class , and why would you prefer to use **function** ?

Comment: sorry I didn't get you , can you explain what is OP ?

Comment: How you relate this to function still confused , please explain .